Data Transfer using BLE among Flutter app & ESP32 (flutter_blue_plus)
I'm a newbie to Flutter and do want a simple functionality wherein I want to be able to send some data to the ESP32 after establishing the communication successfully, As of now, I can connect to the ESP32 without any issues, but I can't figure out how to get it to send data to the ESP32.
Future<bool> connectToDevice(String bleAddress) async {
  try {
    // Create a BluetoothDevice instance using the BLE address
    final device = BluetoothDevice(remoteId: DeviceIdentifier(bleAddress));

    await device.connect();
    print('Connected to $bleAddress');

    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error connecting to device: $e');
    return false;
  }
}

I'm connecting to devices using their Bluetooth Address & it seems to work just fine, (I've added log statements on the ESP to display when a connection is established) but I'm not sure about sending the data , can someone explain how this can be done.

I've checked my ESP32's functionality part using a BLE Scanner , also sending the data so there are no issues on the receiving end.


follow this document https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus . You sould study about stream and characteristic.

Command is send via characteristics .  you can adjust device mtu also . All parts are given in doc.

@RahulKushwaha thanks for the reference, I did manage to get things rolling for the most part except a very weird thing, my app works on all devices in the case of sending data but for a vivo v27 (Android 14) the code doesn't seem to work (data not being sent).. I tried on other Android 14 devices and it seems to work fine there. What may be the issue?

services.forEach((service) async {
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    try {
      if (c.properties.write) {
        List<int> data = utf8.encode(dataToSend);
        await c.write(data, withoutResponse: false);
        print('Object written');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e during writing');
    }
  }

Following is my addition in the above code

debug the code for Vivo mobile phone . check for mtu size of device also .
